# Android Edit Bitmap Channels

Tags: java, android, bitmap, paint, color-channel

It's possible to access the alpha channel of a given bitmap with `extractAlpha()`, but I haven't been able to find any way to actually set the alpha channel of a bitmap.

How can multiple greyscale images be recombined as channels into a Bitmap with Android?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is quite possible to re-combine separate channels back into an ARGB image. You just need the grayscale channel images and an image with the alpha channel you want - note that this is *not* an opaque grayscale image, but an image with the *alpha* you want. You then draw each channel with a `Paint` using the appropriate `PorterDuffXfermode` onto a blank, black-filled Bitmap.

```
// have your 3 channel grayscales and 1 alpha bitmap loaded by this point

Paint redPaint = new Paint();
redPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.LIGHTEN));
redPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(redChanImg, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP));
redPaint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.DARKEN));

Paint greenPaint = new Paint();
greenPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.LIGHTEN));
greenPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(greenChanImg, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP));
greenPaint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.GREEN, Mode.DARKEN));

Paint bluePaint = new Paint();
bluePaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.LIGHTEN));
bluePaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(blueChanImg, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP));
bluePaint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.BLUE, Mode.DARKEN));

Paint alphaPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
alphaPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));

c.setBitmap(resultImage);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, redPaint);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, greenPaint);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, bluePaint);
c.drawBitmap(alphaImg, 0, 0, alphaPaint);

//save off resultImage, display it, etc...
```

With the above code and the following 4 images (red, green, blue, and alpha, respectively):
[image][image][image][image]

We get the following result:

---

[image]

---

*Just a quick note: the red oval is an opaque, red oval on a transparent background - the color doesn't matter for this one, but the alpha does*

Comment: Ah! That's exactly what I need. A bit complex, but looks like it works.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating Bitmaps is a farily simple thing, when to access the pixel (bytes) directly.
To do that in Android you can do it over this approch

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos); 
byte[] b = bos.toByteArray();
```

Now you can do any image manipulation, tranformation or combination you like.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Not quite. I have the Bitmap in a perfectly editable state. I can apply filters, transformations and the like. What I can't figure out is how to edit individual channels, rather than the entire image at once.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with canvas? The following looks like a hack, but maybe it will work. I have not tested it myself.

```
    Bitmap bitmap;
    int color = bitmap.getPixel(1, 123);
    Rect rect = new Rect(1,123,2,124);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    c.clipRect(rect);
    c.drawARGB(50, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
```

Comment: or use a buffer and read/write the color directly from/to there bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(Buffer dst)

Comment: This would certainly work for simple manipulation, but accessing pixel by pixel is far too slow, since I need this to be done in real time.

Comment: I see, you want to use a greyscaled picture as alpha for other picture. I don't see a ready method. You may have to access the buffer directly and do it on the bit level yourself.

Comment: Have looked in the Android source? There could be a hardware accellerated method doing that.