# How to combine two opaque bitmaps into one with alpha channel?

Tags: android, graphics

I have a PNG file with transparency that I'm using as OpenGL texture. I load it in `Bitmap` with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource`, then upload it to GPU.

The PNG file is quite big and in order to cut down on APK size, I'm trying to use two JPGs instead--one with RGB data, and the other with alpha channel (grayscale).

**How do I combine the two JPGs together in one `Bitmap` object with alpha channel?** I tried loading alpha channel as `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8`, then drawing them on top of each other using `Canvas` but no luck so far.

Comment: Ah, I miss the days of a simple BitBlt :)

Comment: I don't now if https://tinypng.com/ is a solution for you... Sometimes is shrink your images with more than 60%.

Greets

Comment: Hi @Dusty, thanks for comment, today I would definitely give tinypng, pngquant and such a shot. Great thing about splitting PNG into two opaque JPGs though is, I can control compression/quality of the two layers individually and precisely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Kevin Dion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560265/android-edit-bitmap-channels/4632210#4632210) to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560265/android-edit-bitmap-channels).  He explains how to combine 4 separate images (R, G, B and A channels) but you should be able to adapt it to work with two images.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. By shuffling things around a bit, I was able to produce my texture from a RGB bitmap and a PNG with just the alpha channel. I'd like alpha channel also to be stored in JPG, so one remaining issue--how to convert grayscale bitmap into ALPHA_8 bitmap.

Comment: Posted a  followup question about converting grayscale bitmap to alpha mask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106122/how-to-convert-grayscale-bitmap-into-alpha-mask

Comment: Found a solution for remaining grayscale->alpha problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106122/how-to-convert-grayscale-bitmap-into-alpha-mask/5121922#5121922

Answer (score 5):

Here's a complete example:

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;

public class ImageOps {

    private static final ColorMatrix sRedToAlphaMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0});

    private static final ColorMatrixColorFilter sRedToAlphaFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(sRedToAlphaMatrix);

    public static Bitmap composeAlpha(Bitmap target, Resources resources, int rgbDrawableId, int alphaDrawableId) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();          
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        options.inScaled = false;       

        // Load RGB data
        Bitmap rgb = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, rgbDrawableId, options);

        if (target == null) {
            // Prepare result Bitmap
            target = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb.getWidth(), rgb.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        Canvas c = new Canvas(target);
        c.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);

        // Draw RGB data on our result bitmap
        c.drawBitmap(rgb, 0, 0, null);

        // At this point, we don't need rgb data any more: discard!
        rgb.recycle();
        rgb = null;

        // Load Alpha data
        Bitmap alpha = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, alphaDrawableId, options);

        // Draw alpha data on our result bitmap
        final Paint grayToAlpha = new Paint();
        grayToAlpha.setColorFilter(sRedToAlphaFilter);
        grayToAlpha.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));
        c.drawBitmap(alpha, 0, 0, grayToAlpha); 

        // Don't need alpha data any more: discard!
        alpha.recycle();
        alpha = null;

        return target;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following: Iterate through width * height of your two images, and use Bitmap.getPixel(x,y) on each one.

```
int alpha = Color.red(grayscaleBitmap.getPixel(x, y)); // grayscale, so any color will do
int red = Color.red(colorBitmap.getPixel(x, y));
int green = Color.green(colorBitmap.getPixel(x, y));
int blue = Color.blue(colorBitmap.getPixel(x, y));
int mergedColor = Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
// save mergedColor in an int[]
```

Then use Bitmap.createBitmap(int[] colors, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config) to create your new bitmap.

Comment: Absolutely.  :)  CPU cheap would be the PNG.  I don't know that it's particularly more expensive than anything else though.

Comment: This would indeed choke CPU quite a bit. I've got some 1024x1024 textures.

Comment: I'm slightly annoyed about this now.  getPixel should be O(1) as it's just an array indexing method.  The double loop is still O(n) where n is the number of pixels.  Do you guys really think there is going to be an algorithm better than O(n)?  Just because you're calling some other higher-level transfer method doesn't mean you're not still iterating through the pixels.  I'd rather hear "that wasn't fast enough when I tried it" than "I didn't try it, but I bet it's too slow to work for me".

Comment: Sorry Micah, I should have checked my assumptions, after all it's not that hard. So on my Nexus One, the Canvas approach takes ~450ms with 1024x1024 bitmap, the getPixel approach takes ~7000ms. I've read somewhere that Canvas operations can sometimes be performed on GPU, maybe that's a part of what's causing such dramatic speed difference.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, pixel-by-pixel aproach you suggested is way shorter and easier to understand. As such it might be a good fit for smaller graphics like 48x48 icons.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks for the followup.  7 secs is definitely worth the increased code complexity of the other method.

Comment: @Pēteris I'm pretty sure there isn't any GPU acceleration of Canvas stuff pre-Honeycomb. getPixel in a loop involves a lot of bouncing between VM and native code while doing a drawBitmap is going to make a single call (or at least a small constant number of calls) to native code for the entire operation.

Comment: @Laurence Oh cool, then I'll definitely have to try compositing on GPU--might get significantly better performance than current 450ms