# How to convert grayscale bitmap into alpha mask?

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap, transparency, alpha

I have a grayscale JPG picture, and I'd like to load it into Bitmap of format `Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8`. Is that possible, how can I do that?

It's straightforward to load alpha channel from a PNG (which can have empty R,G,B channels), but I'd like to use JPG for compression.

This is a followup question to [How to combine two opaque bitmaps into one with alpha channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098680/how-to-combine-two-opaque-bitmaps-into-one-with-alpha-channel)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[ColorMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorMatrix.html) to rescue!

Quoting Android docs, ColorMatrix:

> 5x4 matrix for transforming the
>   color+alpha components of a Bitmap.
>   The matrix is stored in a single
>   array, and its treated as follows: [
>   a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m,
>   n, o, p, q, r, s, t ] When applied to
>   a color [r, g, b, a], the resulting
>   color is computed as (after clamping)
>   R' = a*R + b*G + c*B + d*A + e; G' =
>   f*R + g*G + h*B + i*A + j; B' = k*R +
>   l*G + m*B + n*A + o; A' = p*R + q*G +
>   r*B + s*A + t;

Set up color matrix that takes alpha value from red channel (or green, or blue, doesn't matter for grayscale...), then use it in `Paint.setColorFilter()`. Here's a more or less complete example:

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
options.inScaled = false;

// Load source grayscale bitmap
Bitmap grayscale = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.my_grayscale_mask, options);
// Place for  alpha mask. It's specifically ARGB_8888 not ALPHA_8, 
// ALPHA_8 for some reason didn't work out for me. 
Bitmap alpha = Bitmap.createBitmap(grayscale.getWidth(), grayscale.getHeight(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
float[] matrix = new float[] {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
Paint grayToAlpha = new Paint();
grayToAlpha.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(new ColorMatrix(matrix)));
Canvas alphaCanvas = new Canvas(alpha);
// Make sure nothing gets scaled during drawing
alphaCanvas.setDensity(Bitmap.DENSITY_NONE);
// Draw grayscale bitmap on to alpha canvas, using color filter that
// takes alpha from red channel
alphaCanvas.drawBitmap(grayscale, 0, 0, grayToAlpha);
// Bitmap alpha now has usable alpha channel!
```

Comment: Woudn't this matrix take only the red channel out of the mask? This should work, of course, if the source is really an grayscale. How woud the mactix look like for a regular RGB? In the bottom line `0.333, 0.333, 0.334, 0, 0` I guess. Is that right?