# References on android 2d graphics?

Tags: android, graphics, 2d

Can someone point me to any good references on android 2d graphics. I have already been at the developer site but not much help. I want to know more on the working on the canvas. Right now I am getting a bit confused.

Comment: Tried searching.Didn't get any good references.

Comment: That still doesn't make this Q&A the appropriate place for this question in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if you want a screen that will just display 2d graphics or one that you will be able to manipulate 2d graphics. if you want to display 2d graphics, just google tutorials, there are loads of them up in great detail like [this one](http://jmsliu.com/199/android-canvas-example.html). but if you want to manipulate 2d graphics [here](http://marakana.com/s/android_2d_graphics_example,1036/index.html) is a great tutorial

Comment: Gone through all that.I am looking into the working as i mentioned

Comment: so do you want something like this: http://www.android-dev.ro/2011/12/23/androids-2d-canvas-rendering-pipeline/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762727/how-do-the-pieces-of-androids-2d-canvas-drawing-pipeline-fit-together which explain explain how the 2d canvas rendering pipeline works because still a bit unsure what you mean by 'know more on the working on the canvas'

Comment: Thanks.That goes very deep but really interesting.I am looking forward to more on answers to questions like these http://stackoverflow.com/q/10733883/598714

Comment: id say you would be better of asking a couple of new questions so about specific parts of the Canvas class that you are interested in learning about as just the Canvas class is very broad and there are no real answers or sites that explain the entire Canvas class in detail bar: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html which you said you have already read