# Android: What's the opposite of Bitmap.extractAlpha()

Tags: android, bitmap

I need to do something which exactly the opposite of Bitmap.extractAlpha: Apply an alpha map (which loaded from a file) onto a RGB bitmap (which also loaded from a file).

Yes! Just like "CGImageCreateWithMask" in iOS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Square blog had a tutorial about this just last week: http://corner.squareup.com/2013/01/transparent-jpegs.html :).

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what exactly `CGImageCreateWithMask` does, but if you want another picture to serve as the alpha channel for your `Bitmap`, you can create one as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560265/android-edit-bitmap-channels), which combines four images. I haven't tried it now, but I think for two colors it would look something like this:

```
Paint colorPaint = new Paint();
redPaint.setShader(new BitmapShader(redChanImg, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP));

Paint alphaPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
alphaPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));

c.setBitmap(resultImage);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, colorPaint);
c.drawBitmap(alphaImg, 0, 0, alphaPaint);

// save result somewhere
```

You can also always just work on the raw pixel data of a bitmap using `Bitmap.getPixels`

Comment: Doesn't work for me, since my alpha map needs a little "swizzling". Great answer anyway.